# Joomla 2.5.4 administration screen loading white page on a single computer

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla, administrator

I have a case where the Joomla administrator page will not load on a single computer.

Other computers on the network can access the admin page.

The browser is IE 10:
- I cleared the cache and history in the browser
- I rebooted the PC
- And a complete Norton Anti-virus scan was completed

I can get to the main site.

From another computer I went to the administrator page an cleared the cache.

The computer that is having the problem is the laptop I take home for work.

Comment: First thing I'd try is another browser or using IE10's dev tools to get more information about the request and response. Is there a server installed on the computer?

Comment: Have you tried on the same computer but on a different browser such as Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: also, on a side note, why are you using Joomla 2.5.4? You're 10 versions out of date on the 2.5 series and should be running 2.5.14.

Answer (score 0):

Login as Admin in Joomla and go to the Template Manager. Select another template. If it displays normal or somewhat better in the web browser platform you are using, then the template might not be compatible with that version of the web browser. If it's a commercial template, then go to the vendor and look for updates for it to work with the web browser you are having issues with.